# MVC Partial View fires Document.Ready() with jquery.get() but not Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I recently noticed that MVC's `Ajax.BeginForm` was acting strangly when returning a view. At first everything looked alright, but then I realised all the bindings that happen in document ready were lost. Document ready was not being executed.

Knowing that this works elsewhere, I found that doing the same thing with a jquery get did execute document ready. But as far as I can understand, the two methods are fundamentally doing the same thing. My quick fix was to strip out the helper's Replace TargetId implementation and use it's `AjaxOptions.OnSuccess` to call my `jquery.get()` implementation.

But why does document ready fire when I use `jquery.get()`, and not when I use `Ajax.BeginForm` to replace a `div`?

---

```
// This method returns a the partial view from DoSomething, but DOES NOT execute the 
// partial view's document.ready
using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Somewhere", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "demo" }))
{ %>
    <div id="demo"></div>
<% } %>
```

Example 1. MVC Helper method for replacing a div

---

```
// This method returns nothing from DoSomething, calls getSomething onSuccess and DOES 
// execute the partial view's document.ready
using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Somewhere", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "function() { getSomething(); }" }))
{ %>
    <div id="demo"></div>
<% } %>

// this being the simplified js function
function getSomething(){
    var $targetDiv = $("#demo");
    var url = "<%: Url.Action("LoadSomething", "Somewhere")  %>";
    $.get(url, { }, function (result) { $targetDiv.html(result) });
});
```

Example 2. jquery.get() method for replacing a div

Comment: Could you also paste your document ready code? Any error in Firebug?

Comment: @Gabriel document ready code is as simple as an alert() to let me know its executing. No errors in Firebug. It just doesn't execute the function. I've seen others arguing that document ready is only executed when the initial document is ready (not subsequently loaded partials), but cleary this behaviour differs between the two methods I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest [alternative](https://github.com/IncodingSoftware/Incoding-Framework) way how build rich application without JavaScript code like are Ajax.BeginForm but more flexibility and customizable.

Sample: Get html from controller and insert into dom element.

```
<div id="containerId"></div>
 @(Html.When(JqueryBind.Click)
       .Do()
       .AjaxGet(Url.Action("GetContent", "SomeController"))
       .OnSuccess(dsl => dsl.With(r=> r.Id("containerId"))
                            .Core()
                            .Insert
                            .Html())
       .AsHtmlAttributes()
       .ToButton("Insert button"))
```

You use any dom value for request like are

```
AjaxGet(Url.Action("GetContent", "SomeController",new 
                                       {
                                         Criterie=Selector.Jquery.Name("txtName")
                                        } ))
```

You can look sample on [official](http://www.incframework.com/en-US/TutorialStructure#Ajax_Post) documentation and download sample project [sample](https://github.com/IncodingSoftware/Browsio/) from github.